# Is there a way to show tab index number at the airline tabline?

Tags: vim

After enabling `tabline` on airline, I cannot see the tab index number

[image]

the default behavior is to show the buffer number on the current window, I am trying to change the setting `g:airline#extensions#tabline#tab_nr_type` to `1` in .vimrc

```
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#tab_nr_type = 1
```

and it show nothing:

[image]

this following is my .vimrc file about airline:

```
"airline
let g:airline#extensions#ale#enabled = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline_theme='papercolor'
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#show_tab_nr = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#tab_nr_type = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#tabs_label = 't'
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#buffers_label = 'b'
```

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Were you able to get it resolved? I am stuck in a similar position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `let g:airline#extensions#tabline#show_tabs = 1` to have `show_tab_nr` working. But you will get all buffers collapsed into its tabpage.

Hopefully there is someone knows how to show tabnr without buffers collapse.